# Edge attributes controlling graph plots python igraph

Tags: python-3.x, igraph

My graph has edge labels that overlap due to their length, like shown below

[image]

Is there a way I can get the labels to show vertically alongside the edge, instead of horizontally?

All of this on macOS Catalina Version 10.15.2, in Spyder, python version 3.7.4

Answer (score 1):

I believe that `python-igraph` does not offer any further control over the edge labels at the moment. It is not possible to rotate any labels, nor is it possible to adjust the alignment.

Comment: Which libraries would you recommend to deal with graphs?